# add a text input field to add tags for a specific student

Tags: javascript, html, api

After fetching api which is  https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students doing some steps to create a matching website page. I'm stuck on a step where we have to add a text input field to add tags for a specific student. here is the video showing what to do.

https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/f-3/99398f01-c407-4e28-a8bc-ccaa440b6353/f-2%20part5.webm .

Please check below link which shows the pdf file showing the full assessment to be done.

https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/instructions/f-3/Front-end%20Assessment%20-%20Student%20Profiles-TLXROZXQZRK8IRJ2IUPT.pdf

Comment: Are you able to share what you have tried so far? Which bits in particular are you stuck with about this task?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>Tags</title>
        <style>
   #tags_here{padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  color: #333;
  flex: 1;
    
    
}
input {
  outline: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
  border-color: blue
}
input:focus {
  border-color: green
}
.tag_text {
    
    
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #eee;
  
  color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
  cursor: default;
  
}
.del{
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>

Input tags here: <br/> <input type="text" id="tags" placeholder="Add a tag" onkeydown="search()">
<div id="tags_here"></div> 
    <script>
    var text = document.getElementById("tags");
    
         function search () 
         
         {
             if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                 
                 var x = Object.assign(document.createElement('SPAN'), { className: 'tag_text' });
                 

                   var el = Object.assign(document.createElement('SPAN'), { className: 'del' }, {textContent: '×'});

 console.log(el)

                 
 x.innerHTML = text.value + '&nbsp;' + '&nbsp;';
  
  document.getElementById('tags_here').appendChild(x);
x.appendChild(el);
        document.getElementById("tags").value ="";
        
        check();
    }
    }
            
        function check () {
            var remove = document.querySelectorAll(".del");
            
        for (var i = 0; i < remove.length; i++) {
        remove[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            //Add function here
            this.parentNode.remove();
            
            
        }); 
        }
        }
        
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Can't exactly do what I saw in that video but can give you the code to create tags which I also have made recently although I am beginner too i tried it you can see it here https://codepen.io/gauntletww/pen/JjpPgLV and I cannot snippet the code as I am currently on android, any feedbacks for me would be appreciated too.

Comment: using this I can add tags only in the first data and when im trying to add the tags in the second or any other data it adds the empty tag in the first data.

Answer (score -1):

in App.js,
`Student` component will have `addTag` prop as below

```
<Student key={student.id} data={student} addTag={(e) => addTag(e, student)} />


const addTag = (e, student) => {
  const { tags } = student;
  if(e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value) {
    if(student.tags.indexOf(e.target.value) != -1) {
      tags.push(e.target.value);
      e.target.value = "";
      setStudents([...students, student]);
    }
  }
};
```

the updated students data will cause a `Student` component to rerender that will display new tags being added in `student.tag`

in Student.jsx, `map` through tags and display it in `Student` component

Comment: I'm doing this using html and javascript only. could you please give the code for html and javascript.